# I am facing error in installing pyperclip

Tags: pyperclip

```
C:\Python37-32\Scripts>pip.exe install pyperclip
```

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
>   '"c:\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install
>   pyperclip'